# Sum value within a <input> every time I press a button

Tags: javascript

## 1. Problem

Hello everybody

Every time I press a button it must add 1 to the value found in the input box

The problem is that every time I press the button instead of adding +1 to the value, it concatenates the value like it is a string

Expected result after clicking on the button 5 times:

```
5
```

What is actually happening:

```
11111
```

## 2. Code

```
// the html
<button id="add-one">+</button>
<input type="text" value="" id="output-box"/>
```

```
// the javascript
document
  .getElementById("add-one")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    document.getElementById("output-box").value += parseInt(1);
  });
```

please help :(

Comment: `it concatenates the value like it is a string` because `.value`  *is* a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `input.value` will always return a string. So in order to subtract the value you need to convert it into a number first:

```js
const setup = () => {

  document
    .getElementById("add-one")
    .addEventListener("click", () => {
       const outputBox = document.getElementById("output-box");
       outputBox.value = +outputBox.value + 1;
  });


};

window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<button id="add-one">+</button>
<input type="number" id="output-box">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
// the javascript
document
  .getElementById("add-one")
  .addEventListener("click", function () {
    let el = document.getElementById("output-box");
    // let v = parseInt(el.value) // wrong
    // per comments @PaulRooney, instead when parsing empty string returns Nan
    // so instead use:
    let v = parseInt(el.value) || 0
    el.value = v + 1
    
  });
```

In this way you parse the original value to an int before adding 1.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems with your code. First, you're passing '1' all the times without incrementing. The second one is because you're using the addition assignment operator `(+=)` and this is adding the value that you're passing sequentially as `<input type="text" value="" id="output-box"/>` is a string type. So, try this code out. This should fix it.

```js
        // the javascript
        let i = 1;
        document
        .getElementById("add-one")
        .addEventListener("click", function () {
            document.getElementById("output-box").value = i++;
        });
```